# How to type decimal values (money) from right to left?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Suppose when a field is loaded, its empty. When the user types 1, it says 0.01, then he types another 0 after the 1 (10) it becomes 0.10. When he types another 1, it becomes 1.10.

Just like entering the price of a product. How do I do that on Android? I'm quite stumped to be honest since I've never tried something like this. Is there some special input method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK guys.. I have a temporary workaround. This can't be termed as the perfect solution but its a workaround that works well in my case.

I couldn't figure out a way to stop the stackoverflow error. My workaround? Make the EditText field take input, but display the currency output onto a TextView, and make the EditText disappear from the UI so the user can't see that he is typing just 1234 instead of 12.34.

Here is the code. The addCurrencySign function comes from @ss1271.

```
amountpaid.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                amount.setText(addCurrencySign(s.toString()));
            }

            @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {

            }

            @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {

            }
        });
```

Here's the function that the user posted. It works very well.

```
private String addCurrencySign(String digits)
    {
        String string = "&"; // Your currency
        // Amount length greater than 2 means we need to add a decimal point
        if (digits.length() > 2)
        {
            String pound = digits.substring(0, digits.length() - 2); // Pound
                                                                        // part
            String pence = digits.substring(digits.length() - 2); // Pence part
            string += pound + "." + pence;
        }
        else if (digits.length() == 1)
        {
            string += "0.0" + digits;
            Log.d("TextWatcher", "length 1 " + string);
        }
        else if (digits.length() == 2)
        {
            string += "0." + digits;
            Log.d("TextWatcher", "length 2 " + string);
        }

        return string;
    }
```

Here's the 'invisible' edittext:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/amoundpaid"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#00ffffff" >

        <requestFocus />
```

Here's the field that will show the output text (with currency sign and proper decimal point value):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

I know this is not a optimum solution, but it works. I needed the functionality and this is what I had to do to get it. If someone can fix the stackoverflow error, please post and mods will change the answer to that one (once its verified).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code I wrote for myself:

```
private String addCurrencySign(String digits) {
        String string = "£";
        // Amount length greater than 2 means we need to add a decimal point
        if (digits.length() > 2) {
            String pound = digits.substring(0, digits.length() - 2); // Pound part
            String pence = digits.substring(digits.length() - 2); // Pence part
            string += pound + "." + pence;
        } else if (digits.length() == 1) {
            string += "0.0" + digits;
            Log.d(TAG, "length 1 " + string);
        } else if (digits.length() == 2) {
            string += "0." + digits;
            Log.d(TAG, "length 2 " + string);
        }

        return string;
    }
```

This `addCurrencySign` method is triggered each time when user trying to type on the number pad. The number pad is consist of several digit buttons (just like POS handheld or calculator).

Since you don't need to build a keypad with buttons, could you try intercept the keyboard events, which is described in [Handling Keyboard Actions](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html) and maybe write something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:

            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:

            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:

            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:

            return true;
        ......

        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Maybe you don't have to use switch clause, my idea is to intercept the key entering 0~9 digits and for each 0~9, call `addCurrencySign` method.

Comment: How to do this at runtime? As in, to do this while the user is typing?

Comment: @Asim Please refer to my updated answer. It is triggered each time user typing the digit button, in my app I have a number pad consist of series of buttons.

Comment: I'm trying to use the normal input method (type number). Is there some way I can trigger the above function using that?

Comment: Also, your code goes till 0.99 :) Doesn't acknowledge a third digit. But its a very good example.

Comment: My bad. Was relying on the LOG tags lol. It should be fine. Checking now

Comment: @Asim maybe u'll need to intercept the keyboard event. You'll confine the `EditText` to digit only, right?

Comment: That's already done. Just trying to figure out where to finally use .setText on the EditText. Just tried in afterTextChanged and it caused a stackoverflow error lol

Comment: Why would I want to intercept inputs? If I call your function in onTextChanged, its working fine. The problem is to finally show the string your function returns as the EditText content

Comment: @Asim ah, that was my misunderstanding. So ur problem is when to call `setText`, am I right this time?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31940/discussion-between-asim-and-ss1271)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher(){
  afterTextChanged(Editable s){}
  beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
  onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
}
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Here you will find more info about TextWatcher http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Comment: I tried this method, but it may cause infinite loop and lead to `StackOverflowException`

Comment: You can save your string before setting to edittext and than check if it's the same. Adding condition to one of those methods should solve your issue.